# In Eclipse How to refactor a filename in a project programatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

We can refactor the project names, but I need help regarding the filename refactoring in eclipse in a programatic way. We have a folder under this folder there lies a xxx.zzz file and we want to rename/refactor this file.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click the file, select refactor and enter your desired file name. You may be asked additionally to update references and similarly names variables. Check them both (recommended) and your file And all its references will be updated

Comment: I need to do it programatically. I saw there is move method. But I got an exception while doing it.

Comment: Click the file, or open the file(in case of a Java file), press Alt+Shit+R, now the file's name will be boxed, now edit the file name and press enter to accept the changes

Comment: @ilkeMuhtaroglu: Was it the `IResource.move()` method that you tried to use? What exception did you get?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a class file, you can try the code below:

```
RefactoringContribution contribution = RefactoringCore.getRefactoringContribution(IJavaRefactorings.RENAME_COMPILATION_UNIT);
RenameJavaElementDescriptor descriptor = (RenameJavaElementDescriptor) contribution.createDescriptor();
descriptor.setProject(cu.getResource().getProject().getName());
descriptor.setNewName(newFileName);
descriptor.setJavaElement(cu);
descriptor.setUpdateReferences(true);
RefactoringStatus status = new RefactoringStatus();
try {
    RenameRefactoring refactoring = (RenameRefactoring) descriptor.createRefactoring(status);
    IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
    RefactoringStatus status1 = refactoring.checkInitialConditions(monitor);
    if (!status1.hasFatalError()) {
        RefactoringStatus status2 = refactoring.checkFinalConditions(monitor);
        if (!status2.hasFatalError()) {
            Change change = refactoring.createChange(monitor);
            change.perform(monitor);
        }
    }
} catch (CoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

cu is of type `ICompilationUnit` and you can get a compilation unit from `IPackageFragment`.
You can also replace `IJavaRefactorings.RENAME_COMPILATION_UNIT` with what your need.

Comment: This answer sounds like it pertains to JDT, but the question is tagged eclipse-cdt.